# Find equations of the tangent plane and the normal line to the given surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find equations of the tangent plane and the normal line to the given surface at the specified point $(0, 0, 6)$:
$$x + y + z = 6e^{xyz}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the level surface: $f(x,y,z) = x + y + z - 6e^{xyz}$. Taking gradient of $f$ at point $(0,0,6)$:

$\nabla f|_{(0,0,6)} = (f_x,f_y,f_z) = (1-6yze^{xyz},1-6xze^{xyz},1-6xye^{xyz})|_{(0,0,6)} = (1,1,1)$. This produces immediately the equation for the tangent plane $P$:

$P: 1(x-0) + 1(y-0) + 1(z-6) = 0$, or $x + y + z = 6$. For the normal line $L$, it is:

$L: (x,y,z) = (0,0,6) + t(1,1,1), t\in \mathbb{R}$.